# Durandal shows spinner on history page instead of current page when we do router.navigate()

Tags: html, knockout.js, durandal

I have simple single page application where 3 products are there with few tabs and we can switch between these products. When I use router.navigate from any one product to switch to another product , durandal shows spinner on last page(tab of previous product)which i visited before coming to this product.
Is there any fix for this to show spinner on current tab ?

```
{ route: 'employee/:id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/employee', title: 'details', hash: '#employee/:id', nav:true}
```

this is the route i defined for product one and when i access this in product 2 like     router.navigate('employee/12') it shows spinner on history page instead of current page

After investigation, I found that it calls deactivate of history page instead of current page.
Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Please show some code samples of your application so we can work to fix the issue more specifically?

Comment: Please include it in your post by pressing the edit button above. Also, add 4 leading space to the line of code.

Comment: You should try hiding the spinner on the `deactivate` or `detached` handler on every page.

Comment: I removed that spinner ,but actual problem is ,it calls "deactivate" of history page instead of current page. Why it doesn't call deactivate of current page?

Comment: So it depends on the relationship between the pages you are moving around. What you are saying leads me to think that you have a parent child relation between pages. If you move along the child pages (sharing a common parent), every time, the deactivate of the parent will be called....